# Meaning of "circle of fatality"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Basically, I'm having trouble with the following sentence:

> Difficulty in breaking through the circle of fatality.

I'm currently looking through a random horoscope and I'm finding difficulty understanding what the meaning of this could be. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Your question is very likely going to be considered to be _off topic_ or _non-constructive_ as per the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). FWIW, I guess you could reword _circle of fatality_ to _circle of fate_ and get the gist of it. However, as these things go, these phrases are often referred to as [weasel phrases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word) and such statements are considered to be [Barnum statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnum_statement). Trying to extract meaning from them is an exercise in pointlessness.

Comment: @coleopterist Thanks for the comment. I was just wondering though if this perhaps was some kind of common statement occurring among horoscopes of sorts and if the "horoscope" keyword would trigger in anyone a step towards a more specific explanation regarding some background information of any sort. I can't say anything against this thread being closed as it is in a sense a Barnum statement as you've stated, but I'll keep this open for as long as I can hoping for an answer.

Comment: @BillFranke Thanks for the comment, I didn't know that. I'll definitely look deeper into the link you've provided. Wouldn't the comment be sufficient as an answer though..?

Comment: I've turned it into an answer.

Comment: Horoscopes are often very badly written. The writers try to pep up their language in order to avoid saying the same old thing in the same old way, then they go astray in the search for a new form of words.

Comment: What does the whole horoscope say?

Answer (score 1):

I found this quote on the Net: "[Astrology is fatalistic in its approach. It rules out the free choice of each of us, leaving man merely as a cog in the cosmic machinery.](http://www.astrologie.ws/questions.htm)" I don't believe in astrology; however, I agree that believing that the stars rule our lives is fatalistic: if we can predict what will happen because of the day, time, & place of our birth, then we have no free choice & are merely pawns in some cosmic design. That's the "*circle of fatality*". "*Breaking through it*" is an absurd notion for an astrologer to express